# Release APK not working as expected it hang my device in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

In debug mode (with connected using cable) , my app is running as expected. but when i create APK from top of Android Studio Menu **Build => Flutter => Build apk** this apk when try to install and open that time my app is not working as i expect. It give this errors in Log :

```
I/flutter (31756): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'Diagnostics Property'
I/flutter (31756): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'Diagnostics Property'
I/flutter (31756): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'Diagnostics Property'
```

I try with put INTERNET Permisson in release , debug and profile Manifest file

I first execute `flutter clean` then `flutter build apk --release` but same issue occure.

My Environment

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Linux, locale en_IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
! Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.49.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

This is my flutter run --release --verbose File = [Verbose Log](https://gist.github.com/maulikdadhaniya/75a64224781fcb8c57824372e754997a)

This is my pubspec file = [pubspec file](https://gist.github.com/maulikdadhaniya/3f7756c9ab42962666b5f41039e6dfb5)

And Here is my init Code = [init Code](https://gist.github.com/maulikdadhaniya/3144cfa4d6f901e1380f8c9f1f83e142)

Comment: Reading about the class DiagnosticsProperty I believe the problem is in one of its printLog (<Object> .toString ()); most likely in try and then, trying to handle the error, in catch. "If the default value.toString() does not provide an adequate description of the value, specify description defining a custom description."  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/DiagnosticsProperty-class.html